# nil exception when initializing an SKSpriteNode Object

Tags: sprite-kit, swift3

I get a nil exception error during runtime and I can not explain myself why there is a problem.

First I declare a SKSpriteNode Object like this

```
var destinationSign: SKSpriteNode?
```

and later I define a function that creates this SpriteNode like this

```
func showDestination( x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat){
    destinationSign = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "sign_1")
    destinationSign?.position.x = x
    destinationSign?.position.y = y
    addChild(destinationSign!)
}
```

after that I have a different function and triggers this showDestination function

```
showDestination(x: 20 , y: 40)
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use if let and see if destinationSign is initialized at all. Or just put a break point and inspect problematic sprite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like destinationSign is nil when addChild is called. You should double check the name of the image used to init it, capital letters, underscore, etc…

Try also:

```
if let node = destinationSign as SKSpriteNode {
self.addChild(node)
}
```

to prevent the nil exception (but remember the node will not be added)

You should also consider to use a more generalized function, that could be used in other contexts, as:

```
func show (_ node: SKSpriteNode, at point: CGPoint) {

    node = SKSpriteNode(fileNamed: "sign_1")

    if let node = node as SKSpriteNode {
        node.position.x = point.x
        node.position.y = point.y
        addChild(node)
    }
}
```

But these solution are merely theoretical, given the fact you actually **want** an error if your sprite is not added to the scene.